# setting HTML text in MultiPartEmail

Tags: java, email, html-email, apache-commons, email-attachments

I have java code for sending email with attachment as below.

```
String myEmailId = "xx@yahoo.co.in";
String myPassword = "@xx";
String senderId = "yy@gmail.com";
try {
    MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(myEmailId, myPassword));
    email.setDebug(true);
    email.setHostName("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
    email.addTo(senderId);
    email.setFrom(myEmailId);
    email.setSubject("The picture");
    email.setMsg("<font face='verdana' size='3'>Here is the picture you wanted "
            + "<table>"
            + "<tr><th>id</th><th>Name</th></tr>"
            + "<tr><th>1</th><th>Name 1</th></tr>"
            + "<tr><th>2</th><th>Name 2</th></tr>"
            + "<tr><th>3</th><th>Name 3</th></tr>"
            + "<tr><th>4</th><th>Name 4</th></tr>"
            + "</table>"
            + "</font>");

    // add the attachment
    EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
    attachment.setPath("/Users/alkandari/Desktop/SMART/Fahim/test_small.pdf");
    attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
    email.attach(attachment);

    attachment = new EmailAttachment();
    attachment.setPath("/Users/alkandari/Desktop/SMART/Fahim/test.pdf");
    attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
    email.attach(attachment);

    // send the email
    email.send();
    System.out.println("Mail sent!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception :: " + e);
}
```

All is working fine EXCEPT, the HTML code is displaying as it is.

In Email what I get is

```
<font face='verdana' size='3'>Here is the picture you wanted <table><tr><th>id</th><th>Name</th></tr><tr><th>1</th><th>Name 1</th></tr><tr><th>2</th><th>Name 2</th></tr><tr><th>3</th><th>Name 3</th></tr><tr><th>4</th><th>Name 4</th></tr></table></font>
```

Is there any parameter, email that I will receive will have proper HTML formatted data.

***Note :***

Actually I was using `Email email = new SimpleEmail();` and doing above stuff where HTML part is working perfectly. However when I had to switch to attachment, I had to use `MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer.

Just changed `MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();` to `MultiPartEmail email = new HtmlEmail();`

Comment: you will also need to have the <html> tag

Comment: @MayankSharma : HTML, BODY tag are not needed as `HtmlEmail()` itself understand that whatever is written will be inside `<html><body>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

I want to provide my answer here such that future me (and others) can see the complete code. For whatever reason, probably just me, I found these answers incomplete, or that they did not work for me. Like OP, I was trying to send an HTML based email with a PDF attachment. Here is what I ended up with using commons-email 1.4. Any comments will be appreciated.

Imports:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
```

Build your email object (obviously the actual details here should be yours)

```
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.yourhosthere.com");
email.setSmtpPort(25);
// authentication not always needed depending on your environment
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setTo("to@yourhosthere.com");
email.setFrom("from@yourhosthere.com");
```

Now your message details. Note that my HTML includes the HTML and BODY tags.

```
email.setSubject("Your subject here");
email.addPart("<div>Your html here</div>", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Now the attachment

```
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
attachment.setPath(filepath);
attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);

email.attach(attachment);
```

Now send the email

```
email.send();
```

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT.. do not use `email.addPart` along with  `email.setContent` as the attachment won't be send! Use only `email.addPart`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `email.setMsg()`

But set message body as:

`email.addPart( "<h1>MSG BODY</h1> <u>your</u> name", "text/html; charset=UTF-8" );`